# unexpected integer returned from a C function by calling it using ctypes

Tags: python, c, shared-libraries, ctypes, unsigned-long-long-int

I wrote following C function:

```
unsigned long long int myfunction(unsigned long long int number)
{
    return number;
}
```

and after making a shared library I want to calling it from python:

```
from pathlib import Path
from ctypes import CDLL, c_ulonglong

cwd = Path.cwd()
so_file = Path.joinpath(cwd, Path("mylib.so"))
c_lib = CDLL(so_file)
c_func = c_lib.myfunction

if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_number = 844952973115541
    my_c_number = c_ulonglong(my_number)
    ans = c_ulonglong(c_func(my_c_number))
    print(ans.value)
```

I expect to get back the number I gave, but the following number returns:

```
18446744073471557781
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They python code assumes the c function returns an int. You can fix it by adding:

```
c_func.restype = c_ulonglong
```

Comment: @dAriush Also `c_func.argtypes = c_ulonglong,`, then you can call with `ans = c_func(my_number)`.  Not setting `restype/argtypes` is the #1 reason people have problems with `ctypes`.

Comment: @mark-tolonen thank you for your information. if my function take more than one argument should I set argtypes attribute to a tuple of types?

Comment: @dAriush Yes just like the documentation says 